# Is it possible to run 2 applications?

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

Is it possible to run  2 applications with same context root in one Java virtual machine in WebSphere application server ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but they have to use different virtual hosts. Otherwise, the server can't tell the difference between URL's for the two.